# Manejo de grafo pintado con BonsaiJS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que quiero (entre otras cosas) representar un sistema con un grafo, en el que cada subsistema sería un nodo y cada arista entre nodos representaría la conexión entre los subsistemas que une. El grafo lo estoy pintando con la librería BonsaiJS.

En el grafo que estoy pintando, inicialmente aparecen sólo los nodos. Una vez clicas uno, deberían aparecer las aristas que lo unen con el resto de nodos. El problema es que sólo aparece el útimo subsistema definido en el diccionario (tiene toda la pinta que la última vuelta del for pisa el resto de información, pero por más que depuro no veo el fallo)

El comportamiento de la aplicación es este:

[Comportamiento deseado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGftz.png)

[Comportamiento de la aplicación](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6leiq.png)

El código de mi page template (estoy usando cherrypy para calcular datos y chameleon para pintar esos datos con page templates) es el siguiente:

```js
window.item = {
  "fdp15a01(FDP-1)": { "point": [520, 390], "paths": [[[520, 390], [489, 473]], [[520, 390], [412, 518]], [[520, 390], [324, 502]], [[520, 390], [267, 434]], [[520, 390], [267, 345]], [[520, 390], [325, 277]], [[520, 390], [412, 261]], [[520, 390], [489, 306]], [[520, 390], [650, 390]], [[520, 390], [259, 615]], [[520, 390], [260, 164]]] },
  "fdp15b01(FDP-2)": { "point": [489, 473], "paths": [[[489, 473], [520, 390]], [[489, 473], [412, 518]], [[489, 473], [324, 502]], [[489, 473], [267, 434]], [[489, 473], [267, 345]], [[489, 473], [325, 277]], [[489, 473], [412, 261]], [[489, 473], [489, 306]], [[489, 473], [650, 390]], [[489, 473], [259, 615]], [[489, 473], [260, 164]]] },
  "corrp15a01(CORR-1)": { "point": [412, 518], "paths": [[[412, 518], [520, 390]], [[412, 518], [489, 473]], [[412, 518], [324, 502]], [[412, 518], [267, 434]], [[412, 518], [267, 345]], [[412, 518], [325, 277]], [[412, 518], [412, 261]], [[412, 518], [489, 306]], [[412, 518], [650, 390]], [[412, 518], [259, 615]], [[412, 518], [260, 164]]] },
  "corrp15b01(CORR-2)": { "point": [324, 502], "paths": [[[324, 502], [520, 390]], [[324, 502], [489, 473]], [[324, 502], [412, 518]], [[324, 502], [267, 434]], [[324, 502], [267, 345]], [[324, 502], [325, 277]], [[324, 502], [412, 261]], [[324, 502], [489, 306]], [[324, 502], [650, 390]], [[324, 502], [259, 615]], [[324, 502], [260, 164]]] },
  "drf15a01(DRF-1)": { "point": [267, 434], "paths": [[[267, 434], [520, 390]], [[267, 434], [489, 473]], [[267, 434], [412, 518]], [[267, 434], [324, 502]], [[267, 434], [267, 345]], [[267, 434], [325, 277]], [[267, 434], [412, 261]], [[267, 434], [489, 306]], [[267, 434], [650, 390]], [[267, 434], [259, 615]], [[267, 434], [260, 164]]] },
  "fdo15a01(FDO-1)": { "point": [267, 345], "paths": [[[267, 345], [520, 390]], [[267, 345], [489, 473]], [[267, 345], [412, 518]], [[267, 345], [324, 502]], [[267, 345], [267, 434]], [[267, 345], [325, 277]], [[267, 345], [412, 261]], [[267, 345], [489, 306]], [[267, 345], [650, 390]], [[267, 345], [259, 615]], [[267, 345], [260, 164]]] },
  "fdo15b01(FDO-2)": { "point": [325, 277], "paths": [[[325, 277], [520, 390]], [[325, 277], [489, 473]], [[325, 277], [412, 518]], [[325, 277], [324, 502]], [[325, 277], [267, 434]], [[325, 277], [267, 345]], [[325, 277], [412, 261]], [[325, 277], [489, 306]], [[325, 277], [650, 390]], [[325, 277], [259, 615]], [[325, 277], [260, 164]]] },
  "cmd15a01(CMD-1)": { "point": [412, 261], "paths": [[[412, 261], [520, 390]], [[412, 261], [489, 473]], [[412, 261], [412, 518]], [[412, 261], [324, 502]], [[412, 261], [267, 434]], [[412, 261], [267, 345]], [[412, 261], [325, 277]], [[412, 261], [489, 306]], [[412, 261], [650, 390]], [[412, 261], [259, 615]], [[412, 261], [260, 164]]] },
  "cmd15b01(CMD-2)": { "point": [489, 306], "paths": [[[489, 306], [520, 390]], [[489, 306], [489, 473]], [[489, 306], [412, 518]], [[489, 306], [324, 502]], [[489, 306], [267, 434]], [[489, 306], [267, 345]], [[489, 306], [325, 277]], [[489, 306], [412, 261]], [[489, 306], [650, 390]], [[489, 306], [259, 615]], [[489, 306], [260, 164]]] },
  "icwp15a01(CWP-1)": { "point": [650, 390], "paths": [[[650, 390], [520, 390]], [[650, 390], [489, 473]], [[650, 390], [412, 518]], [[650, 390], [324, 502]], [[650, 390], [267, 434]], [[650, 390], [267, 345]], [[650, 390], [325, 277]], [[650, 390], [412, 261]], [[650, 390], [489, 306]], [[650, 390], [259, 615]], [[650, 390], [260, 164]]] },
  "icwp15c01(CWP-2)": { "point": [259, 615], "paths": [[[259, 615], [520, 390]], [[259, 615], [489, 473]], [[259, 615], [412, 518]], [[259, 615], [324, 502]], [[259, 615], [267, 434]], [[259, 615], [267, 345]], [[259, 615], [325, 277]], [[259, 615], [412, 261]], [[259, 615], [489, 306]], [[259, 615], [650, 390]], [[259, 615], [260, 164]]] },
  "icwp15d01(CWP-3)": { "point": [260, 164], "paths": [[[260, 164], [520, 390]], [[260, 164], [489, 473]], [[260, 164], [412, 518]], [[260, 164], [324, 502]], [[260, 164], [267, 434]], [[260, 164], [267, 345]], [[260, 164], [325, 277]], [[260, 164], [412, 261]], [[260, 164], [489, 306]], [[260, 164], [650, 390]], [[260, 164], [259, 615]]] }
};
 const conf= {
  code: function () {

    var texto = new Text('').addTo(stage).attr({
      fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
      fontSize: '10',
      textFillColor: 'red',
      textStrokeColor: 'black',
      textStrokeWidth: 1
    });
    var ancho = 1;
    var pointsCollection = [];
    var circles = [];
    for (let key in Object.keys(item)) {
      var pathCollection = [];
      var points = item[Object.keys(item)[key]]['point'];
      var path = item[Object.keys(item)[key]]['paths'];
      for (var aristId = 0; aristId < path.length; aristId++) {
        var arist = path[aristId];
        var newPath = new Path().moveTo((arist[0][0]), (arist[0][1] - ancho)).lineTo(arist[1][0] - ancho, arist[1][1] - ancho).lineTo(arist[1][0], arist[1][1] + ancho).lineTo(arist[0][0], arist[0][1] + ancho).closePath().fill('transparent').addTo(stage);
        pathCollection.push(newPath);
      }
      points.push(pathCollection);
      item[Object.keys(item)[key]]['pathCollection'] = pathCollection;
      var circle = new Circle(points[0], points[1], 5).addTo(stage).attr('id', Object.keys(item)[key]).attr('fillColor', 'blue').attr('texto', '').on('pointerup', function (e) {
        texto.attr('x', this.attr('x'));
        texto.attr('y', this.attr('y'));
        texto.attr('text', Object.keys(item)[key]);
        for (let arista of item[Object.keys(item)[key]]['pathCollection']) {
          if (arista.attr('fillColor') == 0) {
            arista.attr('fillColor', 'red');
          }
          else {
            arista.attr('fillColor', 'transparent');
          }
        }
      });
      pointsCollection.push(points);
      circles.push(circle);
    }

  }, // code: function
  width: 1024,
  height: 1024
}; //bonsai.run

bonsai.run(document.getElementById('bonsai-canvas'), conf);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bonsai/0.4.5/bonsai.min.js"></script>

<div id="bonsai-canvas"></div>
```

La variable item viene dada por un python que se le pasa como argumento al page template, en el sistema donde estoy probando la aplicación, el valor de item es el siguiente diccionario JSON:

```
var item = {"fdp15a01(FDP-1)": {"point": [520.0, 390.00000344382397], "paths": [[[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[520.0, 390.00000344382397], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "fdp15b01(FDP-2)": {"point": [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], "paths": [[[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "corrp15a01(CORR-1)": {"point": [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], "paths": [[[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "corrp15b01(CORR-2)": {"point": [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], "paths": [[[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "drf15a01(DRF-1)": {"point": [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], "paths": [[[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "fdo15a01(FDO-1)": {"point": [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], "paths": [[[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "fdo15b01(FDO-2)": {"point": [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], "paths": [[[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "cmd15a01(CMD-1)": {"point": [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], "paths": [[[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "cmd15b01(CMD-2)": {"point": [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], "paths": [[[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "icwp15a01(CWP-1)": {"point": [650.0, 390.0000103314719], "paths": [[[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]], [[650.0, 390.0000103314719], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "icwp15c01(CWP-2)": {"point": [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], "paths": [[[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051], [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312]]]}, "icwp15d01(CWP-3)": {"point": [260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], "paths": [[[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [520.0, 390.00000344382397]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [489.58578432119634, 473.5623892561209]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [412.57426778147595, 518.0250097913462]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [324.9999899913866, 502.583297471343]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [267.8399646859695, 434.46263172765316]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [267.83995693736557, 345.5373829085987]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [325.00000936289644, 277.41669391909716]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [412.57425809572106, 261.97499709630176]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [489.58576882398853, 306.4375943857152]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [650.0, 390.0000103314719]], [[260.0000193715097, 164.83339165482312], [259.9999806284903, 615.1665980137051]]]}};
```

¿Alguien sabe dónde puede estar mi fallo o qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias

(Si alguien quiere contestar en la comunidad en inglés, el link es este: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463320/handling-events-in-multiple-circles-bonsaijs)

Y si alguien pudiese crear la etiqueta BonsaiJS la ayuda sería completísima :)

Comment: He simplificado el objeto item para que el código quede más legible, eliminando los decimales